# JavaScript/jQuery check if file is available to read before trying to load/open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file

I have a PHP file that writes a significant amount of data to a "dump" file, then I am using Jquery to `$('#element').load()` that data from my user interface page. The problem is that I am creating this dump file on the fly and as more and more of the dump file contents are added, every few seconds my Jquery loads that data again. This works fine most of the time. The problem arises when the read happens, while the file is being written to. This halts my PHP script. I check in PHP with is `is_writable()` to make sure the file is available but is there a "`is_readable()`" type of function for JavaScript/Jquery? I know that I could create an "intermediate" PHP file to check, but that would require a significant amount of change to do, is there an easy way to check in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ending up having to use an intermediary php file that waits for the dump file to become available before trying to read from it, then just echos the contents

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call, you should just request the file and if it's not available, you should have an error handler that does whatever you want to do when it's not available.  There is no other way to preflight it unless you invent a different ajax call on your server to give you that info.

If asking for it when it doesn't exist causes your PHP script a problem, then you need to just figure out how to fix that issue so it can just return either empty data or just return an error to the ajax call without messing up the server.

Comment: I have 3 files:
[GUI w/ jQuery $.load] => [Dump is HTML] <= [PHP Creates Dump]

Comment: @Serg Sagan - I don't know what you meant with your comment.

Comment: The Dump HTML file does not interact nor does it return any data it is just HTML so it's not like I can send an ajax request to it and have the dump respond with no data or that it's busy.

Comment: That should be easy to handle.  Your web server should return HTML status code 404 (file not found) and your ajax handler should have an error handler that sees that error response and does whatever you want it to do.  There should be no problem if the web server and ajax hander are configured properly.  You mentioned PHP in your question so I thought you had an issue with server-side PHP, but if you're just requesting a RAW file from the web server, then you should be able to code things to handle it when the file is missing.

Comment: Well it's not missing, it's just unavailable at the moment because PHP is writing to it... The problem is when PHP is writing and the jQuery is trying to load... it crashes the PHP script, so that it doesn't create the full Dump file

Comment: That's a problem to fix in your PHP script that writes to the file then.  You may have to wait for it to become writable or use a different strategy for updating it or handle the exception when you can't write and retry.  You can't control when a web request is going to come in to read it - that can happen anytime.